# Angular 7 disabled status according to click event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Using Angular 7 with Typescript 3.1.1

**Goal**

I want to be able to add click events which cannot be fired again until the previous click event finished (successfully or not).

**Example**

```
<div>
    <span *ngFor="let a of [1,2,3,4,5,6]" (asyncClick)="onClick(a)">
    </span>
</div>
```

whereas `asyncClick` is replacing `click`.
`asyncClick` receives a `Promise<any>` and uses `.then` on it.
While waiting for the `then` to fire, the button should be in a disabled mode.

**My Problem**

Since the asyncClick can be attached to a div,span,button,input,a,img or even a component .., I don't want to create a component to handle this for each type because its just not dynamic at all.

**What I've done so far**

Creating a directive which listens to click events by using

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
```

but I dont know how to get the click event promise. It looks like `<div asyncClick (asyncClick)="myOnClick()"></div>` but, obviously, when the `myOnClick` is fired I dont have the promise to wait for.

```
myOnClick (num: number): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Comment: Create a directive that does it. You'll have to settle for `asyncClickable (asyncClick)="..."` since you can't use an output binding as a selector and shouldn't attach a click handler to all elements at all times.

Comment: @IngoBürk see edit

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using Observable 'Subject'.

**Service:**

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class asyncService {

   getUserData(){
     return from(this.http.get());
   }
}
```

**Directive:**

```
  @Output() debounceClick = new EventEmitter();
  private clicks = new Subject();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clicks.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      asyncService.getUserData()
    ).subscribe(e => this.debounceClick.emit(e));
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  clickEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.clicks.next(event);
  }
```

**Reference:** https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-custom-debounce-click-directive-in-angular

Comment: doesnt it just prevent double clicking in spaces of 500ms?
i actually want to wait for the promise..

Comment: As we are using observable pipeable operator which will support chaining operation. updated answer.

Comment: but.. its not what i was trying to do. myOnClick  is a function returning a promise, i want that the element and click event will be disabled until the promise is resolved or rejected

Comment: you are assuming that you know the method "asyncService.getUserData()"..
this depends on the onMyClick promise. its not like the directive goes to a single method everytime.
i think you really misunderstood my question here. the directive doesnt know what function its about to trigger, all it knows that the function returns a promise which the directive needs to wait for.